# Combo Box on dropdown method only called once

Tags: c#

I am using two combo boxes in one of my programs. The first combo box contains the products while the second contains the categories. I have a method which loads he categories on the second combo box from the database when ever a new item is selected on the first combo box "products". The first time i run the program and select an item it loads from the database but if i try it again nothing loads. Please help with what might be causing this.

```
    private void load_schemes(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable subjects = new DataTable();
        DBConnect con = new DBConnect();
        using (SqlConnection CONN = con.getConnection())
        {

            try
            {

                schemename.Items.Clear();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                String schemeType = schemetype.Text;
                firstname.Text = schemetype.Text;
                String SQL = "";
                if (schemeType == "Family Scheme")
                {
                    SQL = "select schemeID,SCHEMENAME from registration.familyMedicalScheme";
                }
                else if (schemeType == "Insurance Scheme")
                {
                    SQL = "select schemeID,SCHEMENAME from registration.insurancescheme";

                }
                else if (schemeType == "Company Scheme")
                {
                    SQL = "select schemeID,SCHEMENAME from registration.companymedicalscheme";

                }


                adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
                    SQL, CONN);
                adapter.Fill(subjects);

                schemename.DataSource = subjects;
                schemename.DisplayMember = "SCHEMENAME";
                //schemename.ValueMember = subjects.;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }
            finally
            {
                CONN.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Event handler? 2.Programs do not run code like magic out of the blue. 3. Read the docs

Comment: I am using the dropdownclosed and selectedvalueChanged event. I have read the docs and I cannot find the answer.

Comment: Use selectedIndexChanged, and if you use even't handlers it would be wise to show you do in your code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the solution and used Items.Add instead of data binding method and it is now working

```
 adapter.Fill(subjects);
    foreach (DataRow da in subjects.Rows)
    {
        schemename.Items.Add(da[0].ToString());
    }
```